# mtmproxy http get request in script

Tags: python, mitmproxy

How to make http request in response (script)

```
class Intercept:
    def response(self, flow: HTTPFlow):
        t_id = flow.request.query.get('task_id')
        if not t_id:
            return

        rsp = requests.get(
            'https://example.com/v1/tasks', {'task_id': t_id})

        data = rsp.json()


addons = [
    Intercept()
]
```

this code block mitmproxy response

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how to make http request without block (mitmproxy not responding and not request example.com)

Comment: See [ask]. [Edit] the question and tell us what you are trying to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get.

Comment: i don't understand what is not clear."tell us what you are trying " im trying http request in response and this code not working

Comment: I suspect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507362/resubmitting-a-request-from-a-response-in-mitmproxy may be asking for something similar.