# How to make a request inside a simple mitmproxy script?

Tags: python, networking, scripting, mitmproxy

Good day,

I am currently trying to figure out a way to make non blocking requests inside a simple script of mitmproxy, but the documentation doesn't seem to be clear for me for the first look.

I think it's probably the easiest if I show my current code and describe my issue below:

```py
from copy import copy
from mitmproxy import http

def request(flow: http.HTTPFlow):
    headers = copy(flow.request.headers)
    headers.update({"Authorization": "<removed>", "Requested-URI": flow.request.pretty_url})
    req = http.HTTPRequest(
        first_line_format="origin_form",
        scheme=flow.request.scheme,
        port=443,
        path="/",
        http_version=flow.request.http_version,
        content=flow.request.content,
        host="my.api.xyz",
        headers=headers,
        method=flow.request.method
    )
    print(req.get_text())
    flow.response = http.HTTPResponse.make(
        200, req.content,
    )
```

Basically I would like to intercept any HTTP(S) request done and make a non blocking request to an API endpoint at https://my.api.xyz/ which should take all original headers and return a png screenshot of the originally requested URL.

However the code above produces an empty content and the print returns nothing either.

My issue seems to be related to: [mtmproxy http get request in script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55066451/mtmproxy-http-get-request-in-script) and [Resubmitting a request from a response in mitmproxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507362/resubmitting-a-request-from-a-response-in-mitmproxy) but I still couldn't figure out a proper way of sending requests inside mitmproxy.

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code probably does what you are looking for:

```py
from copy import copy
from mitmproxy import http
from mitmproxy import ctx
from mitmproxy.addons import clientplayback


def request(flow: http.HTTPFlow):
    ctx.log.info("Inside request")

    if hasattr(flow.request, 'is_custom'):
        return

    headers = copy(flow.request.headers)
    headers.update({"Authorization": "<removed>", "Requested-URI": flow.request.pretty_url})

    req = http.HTTPRequest(
        first_line_format="origin_form",
        scheme='http',
        port=8000,
        path="/",
        http_version=flow.request.http_version,
        content=flow.request.content,
        host="localhost",
        headers=headers,
        method=flow.request.method
    )

    req.is_custom = True
    playback = ctx.master.addons.get('clientplayback')
    f = flow.copy()
    f.request = req
    playback.start_replay([f])
```

It uses the `clientplayback` addon in order to send out the request. When this new request is sent, that will generate another `request` event which will then be an infinite loop. That is the reason for the `is_custom` attribute I added to the request there. If the request that generated this event is the one that we have created, then we don't want to create a new request from it.